# .bat to move files with specific exiftool color profile output

Tags: batch-file, exiftool

I have a simple .bat script that will output the color profile of jpgs via exiftool:

```
IF EXIST C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\Color_Check_v1.4.5\_Upload\*.jpg for /f "delims=" %%a in ('C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\Color_Check_v1.4.5\_Data\_exiftool\exiftool.exe -T -ProfileDescription "C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\Color_Check_v1.4.5\_Upload\*.jpg"') do echo %%a
```

I am trying to move any jpg with color profile not equaling sRGB IEC61966-2.1 to a secondary folder:

> C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\Color_Check_v1.4.5\Convert

I am having trouble figuring out how to get the cmd prompt to read the exiftool output and isolate files not in sRGB IEC61966-2.1.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exiftool can do this without scripting.  Try something like:
`exiftool -if "$ProfileDescription ne 'sRGB IEC61966-2.1'" "-directory=C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\Color_Check_v1.4.5\Convert" /path/to/target/dir`

Add `-r` to recurse into subdirectories.  Change `-directory` to `-testname` and add `\%F` to the end of your target path if you want to test and see what the results would be without actually moving the files.

By letting exiftool do the testing and moving, it will be much faster as exiftool will only be run once instead of once per file.

Comment: I am working with a user that has had trouble using commands such as robocopy, I Have to provide code such as `C:\Windows\System32\Robocopy.exe` what command is being executed to move the files? Currently the files do not move correctly for this user.

Comment: Exiftool is moving the files in the command I posted.  It can move and rename files as part of its basic function.  I'd check to make sure the path to Exiftool is correct and that the quotes are correct.   And change `/path/to/target/dir` to the actual path to operate on.  Also, you can add `-ext jpg` to limit processed files to just jpegs.

Comment: This makes sense - I simply needed to target exiftool correctly. Thanks for the help!